# Pyinstaller and Python-Markdown - ImportError: no module named 'extra'

Tags: python, markdown, pyinstaller, python-markdown

I'm running into an issue trying to get python-markdown to work in pyinstaller.  I have this code to demonstrate the issue in file called test.py:

```
import markdown

testMarkdown = "blahdy blah blah"
print(markdown.markdown(testMarkdown))
print(markdown.markdown(testMarkdown, extensions=["extra"]))
```

When I run it using python3, I get as desired:

```
(venv) C:\Users\madgrizzle>python3 test.py
<p>blahdy blah blah</p>
<p>blahdy blah blah</p>
```

I run pyinstaller as follows:

```
(venv) C:\Users\madgrizzle>pyinstaller test.py
```

and run the resulting code, I get the following:

```
(venv) C:\Users\madgrizzle\dist\test>test
<p>blahdy blah blah</p>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "lib\site-packages\markdown\core.py", line 390, in markdown
  File "lib\site-packages\markdown\core.py", line 100, in __init__
  File "lib\site-packages\markdown\core.py", line 126, in registerExtensions
  File "lib\site-packages\markdown\core.py", line 166, in build_extension
  File "importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 985, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'extra'
[14432] Failed to execute script test
```

I tried to rebuild using:

```
(venv) C:\Users\madgrizzle>pyinstaller --hidden-import="markdown.extensions.extra" test.py
```

but I get the same error message.

Is there something special that's needed for including markdown extensions?

**Additional Information:**

It appears that the 'extra' extension might be causing the problem.  Per https://python-markdown.github.io/extensions/extra/, 'extra' is a compilation of multiple extensions, including fenced_code and tables.  If I just try to use the tables extension by itself, pyinstaller works **IF** I use the full-name as follows:

```
markdown.markdown(testMarkdown, extensions=["markdown.extensions.tables"])
```

If instead of using 'markdown.extensions.tables' I use 'markdown.extensions.extra', compile using pyinstaller, and run it, it responds back with a missing "fenced_code" module.  Basically, it seems I have to avoid 'extra' with pyinstaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short names for extensions like `extra` and `table` are setuptools entrypoints. I expect that pyinstaller does not play nice with entrypoints. Therefore, you need to use the full importable string name for all extensions.

However, as `extra` uses the short names internally, that means you cannot use `extra`. You will need to call each of the nested extensions separately by their full importable string name:

```py
markdown.markdown(
    testMarkdown, 
    extensions=[
        "markdown.extensions.abbr", 
        "markdown.extensions.attr_list", 
        "markdown.extensions.def_list", 
        "markdown.extensions.fenced_code", 
        "markdown.extensions.footnotes", 
        "markdown.extensions.tables"
    ]
)
```

The only problem with that is that you won't get any `extra` specific behavior. However, when version 3.2 is released, the changes [here](https://github.com/Python-Markdown/markdown/pull/859) will be available and you can add `markdown.extensions.md_in_html` to the list of extensions. At that point, you will get all of `extra` without needing to include `extra` at all.

Comment: Thanks for the response, that helped.